# Is it safe to cache Gmail API message results?

Tags: gmail-api

I am iterating over a Gmail account with many thousands of messages. To save resources I am caching the results of [`users.messages.get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get). Is it safe to cache this data indefinitely? Will the data it returns *ever change*? I assume that it will not but so far I am unable to find anything definitive in the docs or otherwise to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can change - though it might not necessarily change in a way that you care about.

The API itself lets you [change the labels on a Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify) and delete messages.

Comment: Thanks - I overlooked that. Since my application queries based the message id, you're correct in your suspicion that I only concerned about the message content in this case.